# aws ecs fargate can't fetch secret manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, secret-manager

I'm using AWS ECS service for orchestrate my docker container.

Also used Secret Manager for stored and retrieve personal information.

I apply `SecretsManagerReadWrite` policy to my `ecsTaskExecutionRole` and `ecsServiceRole`.

Before using `Fargate`, I just used ECS with EC2.

And it works fine.

But in `fargate`, it throw `NoCredentialsError`

I fetched to secret manager via python script that made with boto3.
(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ko_kr/code-samples/latest/catalog/python-secretsmanager-secrets_manager.py.html)

Is there any solution here?

Thanks.

---

CUSTOM Permission

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
                "ssm:GetParameters"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be sure that the IAM policy you applied has the following permissions :

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ssm:GetParameters",
        "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
        "kms:Decrypt"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ssm:<region>:<aws_account_id>:parameter/parameter_name",
        "arn:aws:secretsmanager:<region>:<aws_account_id>:secret:secret_name",
        "arn:aws:kms:<region>:<aws_account_id>:key/key_id"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Also, be sure that you are using Fargate 1.3.0 (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/platform_versions.html)

But I would try something else to reduce the amount of code.  Since Nov 2018, it is not necessary to write your own code to fetch secrets from Secret Manager.  ECS/Fargate can do it for you.  Just give ECS the permission to access your secret and give the secret ARN in the task definition.  ECS/Fargate will assign the secret to the environment variable.  Your code just need to read the environment variable as usual.

For example :

```
"containerDefinitions": [
    {
        "secrets": [
            {
                "name": "environment_variable_name",
                "valueFrom": "arn:aws:ssm:region:aws_account_id:parameter/parameter_name"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Doc is here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data.html

Comment: You mean that I just assign arn to my task definition, it stored into environment variable automatically? Or I have to additional behavior for it? I want to stored all of my secret manager's variable to my system's environment variable. Because parsed it in my application.

Comment: correct, you can assign a secret ARN to an environment variable in your Task Definition.  At code level, you just need to read the env. variable, like usual.  Under the scene, ECS/Fargate will fetch the secret from Secret Manager.  This reduces the amount of AWS specific code to write into your app.

Comment: I created custom policy(your first code) in `iam - policy` and attached it to `ecsTaskExecutionRole` and `ecsServiceRole`, but it doens't work too. Is it wrong way?

Comment: Also added my custom permission json to my post.

Comment: `ecsTaskExecutionRole` should be enough.  These are the permission the container has access to at runtime.  Just tested on a cluster here and works

Comment: I think your suggestion is related ssm `parameter store`. But I using `Secret Manager`.

Comment: Now, my proposition is both working with parameter store and secrets manager.  Did you correctly use the key `valueFrom` (and not `value`) in your task definition's JSON ?

Comment: Also, be sure to use the key `secret` and nnot store your ARN in the `environment` section.  Exemple from my task def : ```"secrets": [
        {
          "valueFrom": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-1:48000000093:secret:my_secret-SUr3hB",
          "name": "SECRET"
        }```

Comment: I use `valueFrom` correctly. Anyway, I changed `SecretManager` to `SSM`, and it solved. Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe helpful to someone: Be sure to select "ssm:GetParameters" and not "ssm:GetParameter" when creating the policy using the visual editor.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this thread while troubleshooting the same issue. In my case the permissions were properly configured. However, the ARN of the Secrets Manager was not complete.

I had passed the ARN as:

`arn:aws:secretsmanager:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:secret:nonprod-testapp-rds-password"`

Instead of:

`arn:aws:secretsmanager:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:secret:nonprod-testapp-rds-password-wdxsae`

The issue got resolved after passing the complete ARN of the secret as Secrets in container definition